# preg_replace cannot understand the error

Tags: replace, preg-replace

The text I want to replace is as follows (it is Sri Lankan Sinhalese).

මහණෙනි, එක් පුද්ගලයක්හුගේ නිෂ්පත්තිය හේතු කොට ගෙන මහත් වූ ප්‍රඥාචක්ෂුස්හුගේ පහළ වීම වෙයි, මහත් වූ ප්‍රඥාලෝකයක්හුගේ පහළ වීම වෙයි, මහත් වූ ප්‍රඥාවභාසයක්හුගේ පහළ වීම වෙයි, අනුත්තරියධර්මයන් සදෙනාගේ පහළ වීම වෙයි, සිවුපිළිසැඹියාවන්ගේ පසක් කිරීම වෙයි, (අටළොස් වැදෑරුම්) අනෙක ධාතුන්ගේ ප්‍රතිවෙධය වෙයි, (අටළොස් වැදෑරුම්) නානාධාතුන්ගේ ප්‍රතිවෙධය වෙයි, විද්‍යාවිමුක්තිඵලයන්ගේ සාක්‍ෂාත් කිරීම වෙයි, ස්‍රොතාපත්ති ඵලයාගේ සාක්‍ෂාත් කිරීම වෙයි, සකෘදාගාමි ඵලයාගේ සාක්‍ෂාත් කිරීම වෙයි, අනාගාමී ඵලයාගේ සාක්‍ෂාත් කිරීම වෙයි, අර්හත්ත්ව ඵලයාගේ සාක්‍ෂාත් කිරීම වෙයි, කවර එක් පුද්ගලයක්හුගේය? යත්: තථාගත අර්හත් සම්‍යක් සම්බුද්ධයන් වහන්සේගේ ය. මහණෙනි, මේ එක් පුද්ගලයාගේ නිෂ්පත්තියෙන් මහත් වූ ප්‍රඥාචක්ෂුස්හුගේ පහළ වීම වෙයි, මහත් වූ ප්‍රඥාලෝකයාගේ පහළ වීම වෙයි, මහත් වූ ප්‍රඥාවභාසයාගේ පහළ වීම වෙයි, අනුත්තරිය ධර්මයන් සදෙනාගේ පහළ වීම වෙයි, සිවුපිළිසැඹියාවන්ගේ සාක්‍ෂාත් කිරීම වෙයි, අනෙක ධාතු ප්‍රතිවෙධය වෙයි, නානාධාතුප්‍රතිවෙධය වෙයි, විද්‍යාවිමුක්තිඵලයාගේ සාක්‍ෂාත් කිරීම වෙයි, ස්‍රොතාපත්ති ඵලයාගේ සාක්‍ෂාත් කිරීම වෙයි, සකෘදාගාමි ඵලයාගේ සාක්‍ෂාත් කිරීම වෙයි, අනාගාමී ඵලයාගේ සාක්‍ෂාත් කිරීම වෙයි, අර්හත්ත්ව ඵලයාගේ සාක්‍ෂාත් කිරීම වෙයි.

Need to highlight and add tool tips to some text the result was unexpected as follows. showing transparent blue is the error

[the troubled page as an image highlighting the error](http://daham.lk/images/index.html)

the code I use to generate this is

```
function callback($buffer) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php');
    $connection = mysql_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);
    mysql_select_db($DB_NAME);
    $sql = "SELECT word_name, word_meaning, word_page_id FROM popuptable ORDER BY word_id";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    $keys= array();
    $values= array();
    $links;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $keys[] = $row["word_name"];
        if($row["word_page_id"] != 0){
            $links = "<a href='?p=" . $row["word_page_id"] . "'>වැඩිදුරටත්</a>";
        }else{
            $links = "";
        }
        $values[] = do_shortcode('[simple_tooltip bubbleposition="center" content="' . $row["word_meaning"] . 
        ' ' . $links . ' "]<span style="color: rgb(51,122,183)">' . $row["word_name"] . 
        '</span>[/simple_tooltip]');
    }
    $buffer = str_replace($keys, $values, $buffer);
    return $buffer;
}

function buffer_start() {
    ob_start("callback");
}

function buffer_end() {
    ob_end_flush();
}

add_action('wp_head', 'buffer_start');
add_action('wp_footer', 'buffer_end');
```

Experts I need your help here. I cannot do this edit directly in word press due to the data entered from several points and loads of tool tips and links are to be generated. So I created a table in my WordPress database and here I am. All of the code is from Stackoverflow and Thank you for that. the troubled page is [www.daham.lk](http://www.daham.lk/?p=20)

Comment: At the moment I am replacing 3 words ප්‍රඥාචක්ෂුස්හු, අනුත්තරියධර්ම, අනාගාමී and the trouble in අනාගාමී is it is repeated several times.

Comment: Trouble corrected. Thanks but I will keep this to help someone who need the code work. Actually the table structure is (id, word_name, word_meaning, word_page_id) and i have entered a duplicate entry for අනාගාමී. Sorry if I was eating your heads. Thank you Stackoverflow